# how to check if SplFixedArray contains value?

Tags: php, performance, lookup, spl

with a normal array one would use `in_array()` , but in_array doesn't support SplFixedArray, and i couldn't really find any splFixedArray in_array() equivalent, i could just foreach-loop it myself like

```
function spl_in_array(\SplFixedArray &$arr, $value): bool
{
    foreach ($arr as $val) {
        if ($val === $value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but that appears to be ~14-17 times slower than in_array(), and since the whole point of SplFixedArray is performance and memory usage (i think?)...  with this benchmark code

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

$check_iterations = 100;
$nbr_array_values = 100000;
$lookup_value = round($nbr_array_values / 2);

function format(float $f): string
{
    return number_format($f, 6);
}

function spl_in_array(\SplFixedArray &$arr, $value): bool
{
    foreach ($arr as $val) {
        if ($val === $value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$arr = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $nbr_array_values; ++ $i) {
    $arr[] = $i;
}
$splArr = SplFixedArray::fromArray($arr);
$results = [];
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $check_iterations; ++ $i) {
    in_array($lookup_value, $arr, true);
}
$end = microtime(true);
$results["in_array"] = $end - $start;
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $check_iterations; ++ $i) {
    spl_in_array($splArr, $lookup_value);
}
$end = microtime(true);
$results["spl_in_array"] = ($end - $start);

$results["in_array/spl_in_array"] = $results["in_array"] / $results["spl_in_array"];
$results["spl_in_array/in_array"] = $results["spl_in_array"] / $results["in_array"];
$fastest = ($results["in_array"] > $results["spl_in_array"]) ? "spl_in_array" : "in_array";
foreach ($results as &$result) {
    $result = format($result);
}
$results["fastest"] = $fastest;
print_r($results);
```

i get

```
Array
(
    [in_array] => 0.001330
    [spl_in_array] => 0.019912
    [in_array/spl_in_array] => 0.066801
    [spl_in_array/in_array] => 14.969887
    [fastest] => in_array
)
Array
(
    [in_array] => 0.001024
    [spl_in_array] => 0.015516
    [in_array/spl_in_array] => 0.065997
    [spl_in_array/in_array] => 15.152270
    [fastest] => in_array
)
Array
(
    [in_array] => 0.001124
    [spl_in_array] => 0.015159
    [in_array/spl_in_array] => 0.074140
    [spl_in_array/in_array] => 13.487908
    [fastest] => in_array
)
Array
(
    [in_array] => 0.000838
    [spl_in_array] => 0.013853
    [in_array/spl_in_array] => 0.060495
    [spl_in_array/in_array] => 16.530299
    [fastest] => in_array
)
Array
(
    [in_array] => 0.000960
    [spl_in_array] => 0.014201
    [in_array/spl_in_array] => 0.067609
    [spl_in_array/in_array] => 14.790911
    [fastest] => in_array
)
Array
(
    [in_array] => 0.000865
    [spl_in_array] => 0.015183
    [in_array/spl_in_array] => 0.056970
    [spl_in_array/in_array] => 17.553197
    [fastest] => in_array
)
```

so doing it manually with a foreach() is evidently not a particularly efficient way of doing it..

hence the question, how should i check if a SplFixedArray contains something? what is the SplFixedArray-equivalent of `in_array()` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you make use of the `->toArray()` method to convert the spl array to a standard PHP Array and then use `in_array()` you can reduce the time enormously

```
$check_iterations = 100;
$nbr_array_values = 100000;
$lookup_value = round($nbr_array_values / 2);

function format(float $f): string
{
    return number_format($f, 6);
}

function spl_in_array(\SplFixedArray &$arr, $value): bool
{
    foreach ($arr as $val) {
        if ($val === $value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function new_spl_in_array(\SplFixedArray &$arr, $value): bool
{
    $a = $arr->toArray();
    return in_array($value, $a);
}

$arr = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $nbr_array_values; ++ $i) {
    $arr[] = $i;
}
$splArr = SplFixedArray::fromArray($arr);
$results = [];
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $check_iterations; ++ $i) {
    in_array($lookup_value, $arr, true);
}
$end = microtime(true);
$results["in_array"] = $end - $start;
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $check_iterations; ++ $i) {
    spl_in_array($splArr, $lookup_value);
}
$end = microtime(true);
$results["spl_in_array"] = ($end - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $check_iterations; ++ $i) {
    new_spl_in_array($splArr, $lookup_value);
}
$end = microtime(true);
$results["spl_in_array_new"] = ($end - $start);

$results["in_array/spl_in_array"] = $results["in_array"] / $results["spl_in_array"];
$results["spl_in_array/in_array"] = $results["spl_in_array"] / $results["in_array"];
$fastest = ($results["in_array"] > $results["spl_in_array"]) ? "spl_in_array" : "in_array";
foreach ($results as &$result) {
    $result = format($result);
}
$results["fastest"] = $fastest;
print_r($results);
```

RESULTS

```
Array
(
    [in_array] => 0.011569
    [spl_in_array] => 1.094222
    [spl_in_array_new] => 0.157041      // < Using ->toArray()
    [in_array/spl_in_array] => 0.010573
    [spl_in_array/in_array] => 94.583991
    [fastest] => in_array
)
```